# Delphi out-of-process COM server without forms

Tags: delphi, com, automation

I'd like to build an out-of-process COM server with Delphi that does not need any visual forms. The main purpose of that server is to provide some "out-of-process" processing for other Windows Services. 
Is it possible to place COM objects into simple console application? I expect it will (at least) need some kind of message-handling loop inside. 
Can I place it inside of Windows Service instead?

Comment: Have you tried it? What didn't work?

Comment: I've already succesfully build COM server in standard GUI application. And, no, I didn't try it in console. Since I do not understand what is all behind COM communication I'm afraid that the console app (without any Handle, message queue etc.) would miss something. I've googled this and received only examples with GUI servers, none with console as container. Do you think it is worth trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* do message handling yourself, but the Component Services tool in the Administrative Tools that are available in Windows, since Windows 2000 if I remember correctly, provides a way to select an ActiveX dll and have it run from a dllhost.exe process, optionally as an NT-service.

If you really want to you could start a plain exe project and add TAutoObject's to it, [even to an NT-service project](http://yoy.be/item.asp?i282), but there's a little extra work to be done to get multi-instancing, security and concurrency right.

Comment: Thanks Stijn for the link. That I consider a confirmation that COM server CAN BE PLACED in NT services. (Which, BTW, sounds the most reasonable solution for my purposes.)

Comment: OPC servers written in Delphi are actually COM/DCOM servers, and there are few implemented as services. So yes, it can be done with Delphi too.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [SvCom](http://www.aldyn.ru/articles/dcom_in_service/index.html) for an explanation on what's different in running a DCOM server as a service, and for a library implementing it fully, supporting latest Delphi releases also.